# Azure functions 3.0 randomly throws runtime error when deployed

Tags: c#, azure-functions

We are creating an Azure function using .net core 3 and running it locally works fine, and most of the time it also works fine when deployed to Azure, however, after deployments (from Visual Studio) we will randomly get this error showing up in the Azure portal:

> The function runtime is unable to start. Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder, System.String)'.

We don't know exactly what to do to get rid of the error, but creating a new Function project in VS and then pasting in the code resolves the problem, but this is obviously not very convenient.

We are using DI like this in a Startup class:

```
var currentDirectory = "/home/site/wwwroot";
var isLocal = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID"));
if (isLocal)
{
    currentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
}

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

That works fine locally and also, most of the time when deployed to Azure.

The error can be triggered by a simple redeploy of the exact same code that worked the moment before, so this is pretty hard to troubleshoot.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250010) answer your question?

Comment: Hi, any update of this question? Can you offer the `.csproj` file?

Comment: I forgot all about this question and now I don't remember the outcome of this specific problem, but we no longer face the issue.